# Set text size of a TextView with value selected from a Spinner, on button click

Tags: java, android, string, spinner

I would like to set a value with a spinner, and then in my onClick method set the text size of a Remote View TextView (on a widget) to the selected value. How would I do this?

Thanks

I have tried:

```
    String selected;
    Context context = WidgetConfig.this;
    static Spinner spinner;

    ...

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); 

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Log.v(TAG, "OnItemselected started");

                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    selected = "10".toString();
                 Break;
               }
           }


            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Log.v(TAG, "set remote view");
                    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

                    Log.v(TAG, "set txt size");
  /* without this line*/              float number = Float.valueOf(selected.toString());
  /* and this line, it runs fine */   views.setFloat(R.id.tvConfigInput, "setTextSize", number);

        ...

        }
            };
```

UPDATE:

I declared the string twice, so i fixed that, and now it's not crashing, but it not working.
The text size isn't changing.. what to do?

Comment: What is line 254 of WidgetConfig ?

Comment: line 254 is: float number = Float.valueOf(selected.toString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your string selected is null, you did define the selected string in a scope instead of a global var. Change it and it should work

```
    String selected = "0"; // defined outside the function scope
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "OnItemselected started");

                    switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        selected = "10".toString(); 
                     Break;
                   }
               }

    float number = Float.valueOf(selected);
```

Comment: don't really understand "scope" and global var" what should I change it to when I want the value to be fx. 10?

Comment: copy my code and try it. in short: global variable means that it can be used throug the document, and scope means that you only can use the variable the function in which it is defined.

Comment: selected could still be null, it you press the button before the onItemSelected is called. Also check if your view is valid. see also my edit

Comment: Thanks! I edited my code like yours, and then I realized I didn't update my widget, so not it works

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in the following:

Line 254 in WidgetConfig.java is calling a method on a null object.

```
11-20 21:07:29.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2547): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 21:07:29.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2547):     at com.harteg.NotesWidgetPro.WidgetConfig$1.onClick(WidgetConfig.java:254)
```